# powershell search function with regular expression

Tags: powershell

the text file content is:

In this script, we have the following variables:

1. `$input_path` to hold the path to the input file we want to parse
2. `$output_file` to hold the path to the file we want the results to be stored in
3. `$regex` to hold the regular expression pattern to be used when the strings are being matched.

The `select-string` cmdlet contains various parameters as follows:

- `-Path` which takes as input the full path to the input file
- `-Pattern` which takes as input the regular expression used in the matching process
- `AllMatches` which searches for more than one match (without this parameter it would stop after the first match is found) and is piped to `$.Matches` and then `$_.Value` which represent using the current values of all the matches.

Code:

```
$replace_file=@{}
$replace_text_file_path="EMS_checksystem_script\replace.txt"
$replace_file= gc $replace_text_file_path
$result=0
$valr=read-host "please enter the key word"
for($i=0;$i -lt$file_context.length;$i++)
{
    $result=$replace_file[$i] -match $valr

    if( $result -eq 1)
    {
    $replace_file[$i] 

    }
}
```

Result:

key word: `*pression`

> ```
> Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "*pression" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing..
> At line:11 char:37
> +     $result=$replace_file[$i] -match <<<<  '*pression'
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadOperatorArgument
> ```

key word: `pression*`

key word: `press*on`

**NO result**

How can use the `press*on` and `*pression` keywords to search?

Comment: about star  symbol in regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

Read up on regex. You can test regex here > http://www.regexr.com/

Your keyword is wrong, use "." to match any character and "*" to match any number of the previous character.

```
PS C:\>'expression' -match ".*pression"
PS C:\>True
```